# Grep lines for positive number fields

Tags: awk, grep

Consider the following file:

```
a=1`b=2`c=3`d=4`d=5
a=1`b=2`c=2`d=4`d=5
a=1`b=2`c=1`d=4`d=5
a=1`b=2`c=-1`d=4`d=5
```

Can I only show lines, where `c` field is < 0 using awk or grep?

Comment: Does it mean you need all those lines with `\`c=-`? Tried `grep '\`c=-'`?

Comment: `grep '\`c=-'` deserves to be an accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F'[`=]' '$6<0' file
```

I'm splitting the lines by ` or = and printing the line if the sixth field is lower than zero.